# Search disappeared in Chrome Inspect Element

Tags: google-chrome

So it got lost today. Every time I open inspect element, search across all sources tab is missing.

I'm using mac and chrome version is 46.0.2490.71 (64-bit)

Answer (score 3):

You can get search back by clicking:

```
Mac: Cmd + Opt + f
Pc: Ctrl + Shift + f
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/shortcuts

Thought, you need to do that each time inspect element is opened.

Comment: This does not work for me.  Chromium 53.0.2785.143 on Linux.